# Как заменить символы \r\n пробелами в xls-файле?

Tags: алгоритм, excel

Доброго всем времени суток. Файл `*.xls`, в некоторых ячейках перенос на другую строку. Как заменить символы `\r\n` пробелами? Интересует любой метод решения, который наиболее простой.

Comment: Нужно все rn заменить? Внешними средствами пойдет (программка, скрипт)?

Comment: найти rn заменить на "пробел" (пустое место) или ты не про это?

Comment: Не знаю, кто изменил мой заголовок темы, и мой вопрос... в некоторых ячейках есть записи в 2/3 строки пример:

    ывларывдлоаылвоар
    ывлаорывлоарылвавыаываыва
    выалоыврлдаорывлора

Охота заменить все переносы на следующую строку пробелами, чтобы получилось: 

    ывларывдлоаылвоар ывлаорывлоарылвавыаываыва выалоыврлдаорывлора

Comment: Если в VBA, то можно пройтись по всем ячейкам и заменить vbCrLf на пробел. Сейчас Excel под рукой нет, написать и проверить не смогу.. Может кто подхватит? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Меняем символ переноса на пробел:

```
=ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A1;СИМВОЛ(10);" ")
```

Comment: за ответ спасибо!!! уважаемый, воскресенье - день отдыха

Answer (score 1):

Формат ячейки - Выравнивание - Перенос по словам убрать галку

Comment: и разделения нету... супер. есть способ сделать то же самое с разделением?

Answer (score 0):

В меню Excell есть подменю замена.